# How to compare a string with a string array in mongodb query condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
//PhoneProduct is model
//My schema has brand field with string type
var brands = ['apple', 'samsung'];
var QueryResult = PhoneProduct.find().where('brand').equals(brands));
```

Is there any way I get all document that have brand equal to any element in brands array ?

Comment: Well [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) of course. [Mongoose even has a helper](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-in) `QueryResult = PhoneProduct.find().where('brand').in(brands)`

Comment: Thank you. Your code works. I've tested my above code and it also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var QueryResult = PhoneProduct.find({'brand': {$in: brands }})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not campare string with array, for this you need to check it belongs from array or not, 
Try This

```
//PhoneProduct is model
//My schema has brand field with string type
var brands = ['apple', 'samsung'];
var QueryResult = PhoneProduct.find({brand: {$in: brands}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare with for (i) meaning a loop:

```
var myobj0 = { symbols: { $in: ["#" + "AVAX"] } }
find('XDB, 'XCOLLECTION', myobj0).then(result => {
    console.log("These are here", result)
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log("IDS:" + result[i].id)
        bot.sendMessage(result[i].id, message);
    }
})
```

You can also define the strength to match (as in Regex, but more efficient, since MongoDB built in)

```
const find = async (dbName, collectionName, json) => {
    try {
        const collection = client.db(dbName).collection(collectionName);
        const result = await collection.find(json).collation( { locale: 'en', strength: 2 }).toArray();
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Maybe you just want to compare some asset that is already built in too. Please check collations [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document) on Mongo official manual